# setting value using for-in loop javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack, for-in-loop

i am iterating through a bunch of objects in an array and what i want to do is set the value of each objects during loop using for-in loop.
here is my code:

```
StudentFactory.searchAttendances($scope.form)
        .then(function(data) {  
           var attendanceData = data.data.attendanceInfo;
                for(var key in attendanceData){
                  checkDate(attendanceData[key].meta.updated);
                   if(!attendanceData.pickup_time){
                    console.log('hello');
                        var check = checkDate(attendanceData[key].meta.updated);
                        console.log('check',check);
                        if(check.length > 0){
                           if(check.firstDate.pickup_time){
                            attendanceData[key].pickup_time = check.firstDate.pickup_time;
                          }
                          if(check.lastDate.pickup_time){
                          attendanceData[key].pickup_time = check.lastDate.pickup_time;
                          }
                        }

                    }
                    if(!attendanceData.dropup_time){
                      console.log('hey');
                       var check = checkDate(attendanceData[key].meta.updated);
                       if(check.length > 0){
                         if(check.firstDate.dropup_time){
                          attendanceData[key].dropup_time = check.firstDate.dropup_time;
                          }
                          if(check.lastDate.dropup_time){
                          attendanceData[key].dropup_time = check.lastDate.dropup_time;
                        } 
                       }

                    }
                }//for ends
          $scope.attendances = attendanceData;
        }, function(error) {
            console.log('error');
            console.log(error);
        })
```

the **checkDate** function used in between works perfectly all i want to perform is to set the property of the object.

```
     attendanceData[key].dropup_time = check.lastDate.dropup_time;
```

this approach is not working.
any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming `check` will be an object. So your `if` statement after defining `check` will never be true: ` if(check.length > 0)` unless you are setting some length property

Comment: @taguenizy you caught me :) . i should check the object is empty or not instead what i did is use array property to check the empty object.